# Retail POS Software

Tags: automated-testing, hp-uft

How can I start a Black Box test? 
I have a POS software (EXE) installed in my PC with win 10. and HP UFT 14.03 installed. I do manual test. I want automated.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=point+of+sale+testing

Answer (score 1):

> How can I start a black box test?

It sounds like you might already be doing black box testing, as black box tests can be manual or automated. If you don't have manual black box tests, then you'll have to create them, and then perform the test steps.

> I want automated.

If you're question is actually How can I automate tests, then I would agree with 
theonlydanever's smart comment. One would typically need some combination of tutorials, mentors, experimentation, research, experience to do this.